# std::vector do extra operations when shifting elements

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, vector, move

I need to store sorted elements contiguously in memory, so I thought about std::vector and boost::flat_set. I've tried both, and I checked their performance, and althought back insertion is a little faster with std::vector, front insertion is way faster with boost::flat_set. Here's my test code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <windows.h>

// Just a basic movable object for my tests
class Component
{
public :
    Component( void ) :
        id( 0 ),
        name( "default" ),
        data( 100 )
    {
    }

    Component( uint32_t id ) :
        id( id ),
        name( "default" ),
        data( 100 )
    {
    }

    Component( Component&& component ) throw() :
        id( std::move( component.id ) ),
        name( std::move( component.name ) ),
        data( std::move( component.data ) )
    {
    }

    Component& operator=( Component&& component ) throw()
    {
        id = std::move( component.id );
        name = std::move( component.name );
        data = std::move( component.data );
        return ( *this );
    }

    uint32_t    get_id( void ) const
    {
        return ( id );
    }

private :
    uint32_t                id;
    std::string             name;
    std::vector< uint32_t > data;
};

// This object can be sorted
inline bool operator<( const Component& component1, const Component& component2 )
{
    return ( component1.get_id() < component2.get_id() );
}

#define COMP_NB 1000000

int main( void )
{
    /*******************************/
    /* Test vector insertion speed */
    /*******************************/
    std::vector< Component > vector;

    vector.reserve( COMP_NB + 1 );

    std::cout << "Push back components in the vector: ";
    auto startTime = boost::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    // Back insertion
    for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < COMP_NB; ++i )
    {
        vector.push_back( Component( i + 1 ) );
    }

    auto thisTime = boost::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << boost::chrono::duration_cast< boost::chrono::milliseconds >( thisTime - startTime ).count() << "ms" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Insert one component at the beginning of the vector: ";
    startTime = boost::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    // Front insertion (all components are shifted)
    vector.insert( vector.begin(), Component( 0 ) );

    thisTime = boost::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << boost::chrono::duration_cast< boost::chrono::milliseconds >( thisTime - startTime ).count() << "ms" << std::endl;

    /*********************************/
    /* Test flat_set insertion speed */
    /*********************************/
    boost::container::flat_set< Component > flat_set;

    flat_set.reserve( COMP_NB + 1 );

    std::cout << "Push back components in the flat_set: ";
    startTime = boost::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    // Back insertion
    for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < COMP_NB; ++i )
    {
        flat_set.insert( Component( i + 1 ) );
    }

    thisTime = boost::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << boost::chrono::duration_cast< boost::chrono::milliseconds >( thisTime - startTime ).count() << "ms" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Insert one component at the beginning of the flat_set: ";
    startTime = boost::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    // Front insertion (all components are shifted)
    flat_set.insert( Component( 0 ) );

    thisTime = boost::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << boost::chrono::duration_cast< boost::chrono::milliseconds >( thisTime - startTime ).count() << "ms" << std::endl;

    system( "PAUSE" );

    return ( 0 );
}
```

And the output :

> Push back components in the vector: 852ms
>   Insert one component at the beginning of the vector: 59ms
>   Push back components in the flat_set: 912ms
>   Insert one component at the beginning of the flat_set: 16ms

Front insertion is 3.6x faster with flat_set! So I ran another test, cause I wanted to see if my move functions were used, and I found something strange. Here's the new code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <windows.h>

// Just a basic movable object for my tests
class Component
{
public :
    Component( void ) :
        id( 0 ),
        name( "default" ),
        data( 100 )
    {
        std::cout << "Default constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Component( uint32_t id ) :
        id( id ),
        name( "default" ),
        data( 100 )
    {
        std::cout << "Custom constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Component( Component&& component ) throw() :
        id( std::move( component.id ) ),
        name( std::move( component.name ) ),
        data( std::move( component.data ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Move constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Component& operator=( Component&& component ) throw()
    {
        std::cout << "Move assignment operator" << std::endl;
        id = std::move( component.id );
        name = std::move( component.name );
        data = std::move( component.data );
        return ( *this );
    }

    uint32_t    get_id( void ) const
    {
        return ( id );
    }

private :
    uint32_t                id;
    std::string             name;
    std::vector< uint32_t > data;
};

// This object can be sorted
inline bool operator<( const Component& component1, const Component& component2 )
{
    return ( component1.get_id() < component2.get_id() );
}

#define COMP_NB 1

int main( void )
{
    /*******************************/
    /* Test vector insertion speed */
    /*******************************/
    std::vector< Component > vector;

    vector.reserve( COMP_NB + 1 );

    std::cout << "-- Push back one component in the vector: " << std::endl;

    // Back insertion
    for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < COMP_NB; ++i )
    {
        vector.push_back( Component( i + 1 ) );
    }

    std::cout << "-- Insert one component at the beginning of the vector: " << std::endl;

    // Front insertion (the other component is shifted)
    vector.insert( vector.begin(), Component( 0 ) );

    std::cout << std::endl;

    /*********************************/
    /* Test flat_set insertion speed */
    /*********************************/
    boost::container::flat_set< Component > flat_set;

    flat_set.reserve( COMP_NB + 1 );

    std::cout << "-- Push back one component in the flat_set: " << std::endl;

    // Back insertion
    for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < COMP_NB; ++i )
    {
        flat_set.insert( Component( i + 1 ) );
    }

    std::cout << "-- Insert one component at the beginning of the flat_set: " << std::endl;

    // Front insertion (the other component is shifted)
    flat_set.insert( Component( 0 ) );

    system( "PAUSE" );

    return ( 0 );
}
```

The new output :

> -- Push back one component in the vector:
>   Custom constructor
>   Move constructor
>   -- Insert one component at the beginning of the vector:
>   Custom constructor
>   Move constructor
>   Move constructor
>   Move assignment operator
>   Move assignment operator
>   
>   -- Push back one component in the flat_set:
>   Custom constructor
>   Move constructor
>   -- Insert one component at the beginning of the flat_set:
>   Custom constructor
>   Move constructor
>   Move assignment operator

There's something strange here. Flat_set behaviour seems normal :

> -- Insert one component at the beginning of the flat_set:
>   Custom constructor //Ok, I asked the creation of a new component
>   Move constructor //Ok, the flat_set need to shift the previous component in a new position
>   Move assignment operator //OK, the new component need to be moved to the front of the flat_set

But what about the vector?

> -- Insert one component at the beginning of the vector:
>   Custom constructor //Ok, I asked the creation of a new component
>   Move constructor //Ok, the vector need to shift the previous component in a new position
>   Move constructor //Wait... what?
>   Move assignment operator //OK, the new component need to be moved to the front of the vector
>   Move assignment operator //Wtf?

I tried with more components, and the vector behaviour is the same : it keep doing all move operations twice. Why? Can it be avoided? If not, should I stick to flat_set (I'll sometimes need to shift my data)?

[Edit] : Here's the output with 10 components being inserted in back and 1 being inserted in front, and with id of components being constructed or moved :
http://pastebin.com/SzT5M8yP

[Edit 2] : I did the same test with boost::container::vector, and the output (and the speed!) is identical to flag_set. Is it a problem with the Microsoft Implementation of vector? O.o

[Edit 3] : Problem submitted to Microsoft : https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/801205/std-vector-do-extra-operations-when-shifting-elements

Comment: It might be a case of using sub-functions within vector... is this an optimized build ? (calls to copy/move constructors can be elided)

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention this. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and my tests are made with the default Release setup, so yes, optimisations are enabled.

Comment: Boost header paths should be `boost` not `Boost`. Both work on Windows because the filesystem is case-insensitive, but using `Boost` just creates a needless portability problem.

Comment: That's true, but on the project I'm actualy working, I'm using DX11 and win32 API so portability isn't really a concern here. ;)

Comment: Except you've pasted the code on SO now, and it's a PITA for people (e.g. me) to have to fix the paths to run your code on their own platforms.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. Sorry about this, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not doing *all* move operations twice, if your vector had more than one element in it you would see that only *some* operations happen twice.

To insert an rvalue at the beginning of a vector of N elements (with sufficient capacity)  a typical approach is:

1. Move construct new element at index N from element at index N-1
      `new (_M_data+N) T(_M_data[N-1]);`
      `_M_size += 1;`
2. Move assign elements at indices 0 to N-2 to indices 1 to N-1
      `for (int i = N-1; i > 0; --i)`
          `_M_data[i] = std::move(_M_data[i-1]);`
3. Move construct temporary and move assign it to index 0
      `_M_data[0] = T(std::move(arg));`

This means you will see one move construction, followed by (N-1) move assignments (in your case the vector only has one element so you see nothing in step 2) and then a move construction and a move assignment.

In step 3 the temporary is constructed because the same insertion logic is used for `emplace` as `insert`, so it actually does `T(std::move(args)...)` with zero or more args, in the case where there is just one argument of type `T` it would have been possible to just do `_M_data[0] = std::move(arg);` and avoid a move construction.

I'm not sure why you see an extra move assignment at the end, GCC's standard library implementation doesn't do that and I'm not sure why it's needed.  You could quite easily modify your code to print the identity of the objects being moved constructed/assigned, to see *which* elements are being moved twice, that might shed some more light on it.

Comment: I added the output with 10 components and the id of the ones being moved, but as you can see, all operations are multiplied with the vector. I don't understand why, but where the flat_set call only once the assignment operator, the vector call the move constructor + the assignment operator twice. It's probably related to the fact the flat_set is moving the components in good order, while the vector is apparently moving them in a complete random way.
I'm really lost here, cause Components are ordered and stored contiguously in both the flat_set and the vector.

Comment: Wow, interesting, that is indeed doing everything twice! With GCC the output is almost identical to `flat_set` with the addition of a single `Move constructor of component: 0` line before the last move assignment, which is as I explained in my answer above, it does `_M_data[0] = T(std::move(arg));` where actually `_M_data[0] = std::move(arg);` would be sufficient.  I have no idea what the Microsoft library is doing there.

Comment: I tried with boost::container::vector, and the output/perfs are identical to flag_set! It is a problem with Microsoft vector impl?

Comment: From what I've seen of the Microsoft vector implementation, it is way too complicated when compared to libstdc++ or libc++, so I wouldn't be surprised in the least. It could also be that MSVC is simply not as good at eliding copies as GCC.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, I don't think there's any elision happening with GCC, the moving is done through references or in a loop, not returning by value and I don't think anything is eligible for elision.

Comment: But what am I supposed to do? Performances are crucial in my project, should I avoid to use std::vector and use the Boost vector instead (what a mess)?

Comment: If you need to frequently insert anywhere except the end then `vector` is a poor choice anyway. Have you actually measured if the performance is a problem, rather than just counting operations? i.e. are moves actually expensive for your type? Can you make them cheap? Can you use `std::deque` instead of `vector`? If you need to keep it sorted `boost::flat_set` is a good choice.  If you need `std::vector`, can you use `vector<unique_ptr<Componant>>` instead, to make it cheaper to shuffle elements?

Comment: Most of the time, I will insert elements at the end of my vector. It can happen that I need to insert elements anywhere, but it will not occur often. My first requirement is to have my elements stored contiguously in memory (the reason I can't use pointers) in order to have best CPU cache usage possible, cause my elements will be processed several times by seconds (real time application), while elements insertion will be rare. And with move semantic, shifting 800mo of data in memory without realloc is surprisingly fast (16ms). So I think I'll stick to vector and flat_set. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

3 years later, this is what I get in my mailbox :

> Greetings from Microsoft Connect!
>
> This notification was generated for feedback item: std::vector do
>   extra operations when shifting elements which you submitted at
>   theMicrosoft Connect site.
>
> Hi,
>
> Thanks for reporting this bug. I've fixed it by thoroughly overhauling
>   vector for correctness and performance, and this fix will be available
>   in VS "15" RC. Previously, insertion/emplacement called rotate() in
>   certain situations. Now we sequence our actions more intelligently,
>   avoiding the need to rotate elements around.
>
> Stephan T. Lavavej Principal Software Engineer, Visual C++ Libraries
>   stl@microsoft.com
>
> You may receive a general "Feedback Item Updated" notification as
>   well, if any other changes were made by Microsoft.
>
> Thank you for using Microsoft Connect!
>
> Regards,
>
> the Microsoft Connect Team
>
> Please do not reply directly to this message, as it is generated from
>   an unmonitored email account. If you have comments related to your
>   Feedback, please enter it in the Comments section (post a comment to
>   Microsoft) of your Feedback item by navigating to the Feedback item in
>   the link above.
>
> If you are having trouble accessing the Feedback link above, please go
>   to the http://connect.microsoft.com/help/default.aspx page to report
>   the issue, In your submission, please make sure to paste a copy the
>   link above into the report.

Hurrah! It will be fixed soon. :D Granted it's a bit late, but it's still a good thing.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that `std::vector` is growing the size of the vector by allocating a new vector, copying the current singular value into the new vector, and then inserting the new value.  Try removing the call to `reserve` so that the memory management of `std::vector` work for you.

Comment: I already tried, and I got the same output, with one supplementary move constructor call.

Comment: The call to `reserve` ensures it _doesn't_ need to create a new vector, removing that call isn't going to change the behavoiur seen.